# Linear regression: Coverage rate of confidence interval of mean response is poor

Tags: regression, confidence-interval

My understanding of the 95% confidence interval is the interval should contain the true value 95% of the time. Therefore, I test it with the linear regression confidence interval for the mean response.

Here is a reproducible r code:

```
set.seed(1234)

n <- 100

x <- runif(n,0,10)

y <- x+rnorm(n)

fit <- lm(y~x)

result <- cbind(as.data.frame(predict.lm(fit,interval="confidence")),y)

result$inside <- with(result,lwr<=y & upr>=y)

mean(result$inside)
[1] 0.24
```

The results show the coverage rate of the 95% confidence interval for the mean response only has coverage rate of **24%**. Why is this happening and what am I missing?

Comment: The confidence interval is for the (conditional) *mean* (the regression line) not the individual values `y` which you seem to be testing. To check coverage, you'd need to repeat the procedure a bunch of times, not just once.

Comment: As mentioned in the linked post, I am using predicted response to test the coverage of confidence interval. Switching to prediction interval would yield desired result.